# If jstat is deprecated, what should I use instead?

Tags: java, jstat

Suddenly I've found out that `jstat` [is deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstat.html):

> The jstat tool displays performance statistics for an instrumented
>   HotSpot Java virtual machine (JVM). The target JVM is identified by
>   its virtual machine identifier, or vmid option described below.
>
> NOTE: This utility is unsupported and **may not be available in future
>   versions** of the J2SE SDK. It is not currently available on Windows 98
>   and Windows ME platforms.

I haven't developed anything on Windows for years, but nevertheless the question is - what should I use instead, which tool (or set of tools) nowadays is considered the best substitute for that kind of monitoring I can get using `jstat`?

**Update:** pure CLI tools are preferable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation says that it's unsupported (not quite deprecated yet) since JDK 5 (which you linked), yet it's still present in JDK 6, 7 and OpenJDK 8. I'm not too worried about its disappearance in the short term, especially since it doesn't have a replacement ([jcmd](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jcmd.html) doesn't have an equivalent command).

Besides, the [tools and utilities directory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/index.html#monitor) says it *is* supported, except on Windows 98 & ME. Then again it says right above that it's unsupported and experimental..

---

One caveat though: last time I checked, it didn't support G1, but then, neither did JConsole/JVisualVM. It doesn't mean it can't be adapted.

Comment: well, let us hope it won't be removed in nearest future)

Answer (score 3):

I think you can go for either [VisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/index.html) (or) [Jconsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/jconsole.html)

Both are good tools for JVM monitoring.

Comment: No, good if you only have a console (i,e non-windowed) environment

Comment: @PaulTaylor: Could you be more specific on console environment, I have experience using these only on Windows (and I know these won't work on Unix unless you have some X downloaded on those, is that what you mean)?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Visual VM for Sun JVMs.  Get the latest version from SourceForge and install *all* the plugins.  You'll be happy with the visual representation for threads, CPU, memory, etc.

Comment: honestly, my work is tightly connected with data visualization, may be this is the reason why I am a huge proponent of CLI tools )))