# Why jstat doesn't work after java update on linux?

Tags: java, linux, jstat

After updating Java `1.7.0.71` to `1.7.0_75`, `jstat` doesn't work anymore. I've tried to stop the application, delete `/tmp/hsperfdata_*` and restart the application, but `/tmp/hsperfdata_*` doesn't exist and `jstat` failed.

```
/opt/jdk/bin/jstat -gc myApp
1959 not found
CRITICAL: Can't get GC statistics
```

Could it be a bug in the latest Java update?

Comment: No, it isn't a permission problem.

Comment: OK - comment deleted.  It appears the jdk behaviour for using /tmp for these tools has been unstable a number of times, so I think it is a bug.  Note that [oracle docs say jstat is unsupported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12716416/if-jstat-is-deprecated-what-should-i-use-instead) although it obviously still ships.  If you google "jdk source get_temp_directory()" you see a lot of problems with tools like jstat and jstack due to the tmp location not being correct in the jvm (mostly old, some new).  it looks like that's what you're seeing.